# Circular Reveals take 300ms longer on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using `ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(View, int, int, float, float);` to create a circular reveal. There are some elements inside of the root view that are timed to the reveal itself. However, I noticed that these timings seemed off in Marshmallow so I investigated. What I found is that the reveal duration (timed with `System.currentTimeMillis()` in a start end end action are always 300ms longer on Marshmallow.
I tested it on the following phones:
Lollipop: Sony Xperia Z5 Compact, Nexus 7, Blackberry Priv
Marshmallow, Nexus 5X, Nexus 6

And with the following durations: 100ms, 200ms, 400ms, 800ms, and 4000ms

All of the Lollipop devices were consistent and all of the Marshmallow devices were 300ms slower.

Does anybody know why this is happening or has anybody noticed this behavior?